# HTML/CSS: Cannot get text-ellipsis to work with two side-by-side text fields

Tags: html, css

The objective is to have a header section, which consists of two text fields:

- First name
- Last name

The rules are straightforward:

- The header should be one line only (no wrap)
- The first name is aligned to the left of the header
- The last name is aligned to the right of the header
- If the text doesn't fit, I want the last name to be truncated with an ellipsis
- (UPDATE): I can't set a fixed width (i.e. px) since the header can be displayed on a multitude of devices of different sizes, from desktop monitors to iPhones

Although the rules are straightforward, I simply can't figure out how to do it with HTML/CSS. I've been trying two approaches: one with floated P's, and one with a TABLE and TD's. Neither work. See HTML/CSS and JSFiddle below:

**HTML**

```
<!-- First Attempt: With DIV -->
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
        <p class="header-text first">First Name</p>
        <p class="header-text last">Long last name: xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx</p>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<!-- Second Attempt: With TABLE -->
<div class="header">
    <table class="header-container">
        <tr>
            <td class="header-text first">First Name</td>
            <td class="header-text last">Long last name: xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
DIV.header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* ----- First Attempt ----- */
DIV.header-container {
    white-space: nowrap; /*prevent header from line breaking*/
}

P.header-text {
    font-size: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap; /*prevent each text block from line breaking*/
}

P.first {
    float: left; /*align to left*/
}

P.last {
    float: right; /*align to right*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* ----- Second Attempt ----- */
TD.header-text
{
    font-size: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap; /*prevent each text block from line breaking*/
}

TD.first {
    width: 100%; /*take up all the space, so last name is right-aligned*/
}

TD.last {
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4gTG/)

What am I missing? Why isn't the above working?

Comment: Width is important to mention here. try adding `P.last { width: 240px;}` then it ll work.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention: I cannot set a specific width. The header could be used on a small device or a large screen, so fixed-widths are out of the question (which no doubts increases the complexity).

Comment: Try this define width of your .last calss demo is this  http://jsfiddle.net/g4gTG/2/

Comment: That's a different issue. but you cant show ellipsis without mentioning width here.

Comment: You can specify width in percentage % also.

Comment: Your approach works if I set, say, 50% for each field. Then the ellipsis shows. But ideally it would be more 'flexible', i.e. the first name should be able to take more than 50% if the first name is long and the second name is very short. This being said your solution does work. I suggest you edit your solution and I'll vote it up.

Comment: Try different combinations of width, min-width, max-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width is important to mention here.

```
P.header-text {
    font-size: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width:50%;
}
```

New JSFiddle accessible here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4gTG/3/

Comment: excuse me. but where is TD here?

Comment: Please read the question clearly. "one with floated P's, and one with a TABLE and TD's. Neither work"